# Razorpay web API signin alert

Tags: reactjs, razorpay

I integrated Razorpay API into my MERN app. I created an instance of Razorpay and passed the options variable to it. Everything is working properly except when I click the PAY ₹100 button a new window opens up and asks for a username and password. I have already passed the test mode key_id generated from the Razorpay dashboard. Here's the options object:

```
const options = {
                "key": settings.RAZORPAY_KEY_ID, 
                "amount": settings.PLANS[plan.name].price[plan.duration],
                "currency": plan.currency,
                "name": settings.RECEIPT_NAME,
                "description": "Test Transaction",
                "order_id": order._id,
                "handler": response => {
                    setLoading(true)
                    const payment = {
                        razorpay_payment_id: response.razorpay_payment_id,
                        razorpay_order_id: response.razorpay_order_id,
                        razorpay_signature: response.razorpay_signature
                    }
                    server.post(`/api/order/${order._id}/pay`, payment)
                    .then(response => {
                        const order = response.data;
                        if(order.payment_id) {
                            setStatus({
                                error: false,
                                message: "Plan Upgraded Successfully",
                                code: response.status
                            })
                            props.updatePlan(plan, order.payer.id)
                        }
                        else 
                            setStatus({
                                error: true,
                                message: "Source was not authenticated",
                                code: response.status
                            })
                        setShowAlert(true)
                        setPlan({
                            name: "premium",
                            currency: "INR",
                            duration: "one_month"
                        })
                        setLoading(false)
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        setStatus({
                            error: true,
                            message: error.response ? error.response.data.message : error.message,
                            code: error.response ? error.response.status : 500
                        })
                        setShowAlert(true)
                    })
                },
                "prefill": {
                    "name": user.firstname + " " + user.lastname,
                    "email": user.email,
                    "contact": user.mobile
                },
                "theme": {
                    "color": "#3399cc"
                }
            }
```

Here's the screenshot of authentication.
[image]

Here's the error if I click on cancel:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code":"BAD_REQUEST_ERROR",
        "description":"Please provide your api key for authentication purposes.",
        "source":"NA",
        "step":"NA",
        "reason":"NA",
        "metadata":{}
    }
}
```

This was not happening before I switched on the Live mode. How do I get rid of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please do not make use of the test VISA card i.e **4111 1111 1111 1111** instead, make use of the master card i.e 5104 0600 0000 0008 for testing purpose.

https://razorpay.com/docs/payment-gateway/test-card-upi-details/

Comment: How did you come to know that I was using the card number 4111 1111 1111 1111 and is incorrect? Have you experienced this before?

Answer (score 0):

your testing card is incorrect please check your testing card number with https://razorpay.com/docs/payment-gateway/test-card-upi-details/
use testing only with domestic card